# laravel pagination : Call to a member function render() on array

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

[image: The Following error occurs:]

In laravel controller I have following code:

```
public function getAdmins(){
    //$users = $this->user->all();

    $search[] =array();
    $search['name']= Input::get('name','');
    $search['uname']= Input::get('uname','');
    $search['role']= Input::get('role','');

    $users = $this->user->findUsers($search);

    $exceptSuperadmin = array();
    foreach($users as $user){
        if(!$user->isUser())
            $staffs[] = $user;
    }
    $users = @$staffs;

    return view('users::admins.list')->with('staffs',$users)->with('search',$search);
}
```

In Model I have:

```
public function findUsers($search)
{

    return self::where('name','like','%'.$search['name'].'%')
    ->where('username','like','%'.$search['uname'].'%')
    ->where('role','like','%'.$search['role'].'%')
    ->paginate(5);

}
```

And In blade file I have:

```
@if($staffs)

@foreach($staffs as $staff)
        <!-- Some code here to loop array -->
     @endforeach

@else
      No Staffs

@endif
```

`{!! $staffs->render() !!}  Error comes at this line`

I am not geeting why this error comes....staffs is an array and render() a function to echo the pagination pages...but can't getting the error...Anybody to help.

Comment: render function is not available on an array. Its only available in a collection. After paginating the result, you are adding them into an array. Thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: No, render() works on the PaginationAware object, not on the array you created with it

Comment: Then what is the solution...In normal cases we do the pagination as I did above...the laravel documentation also tells this way as I did above..but error comes

Comment: @Damien Pirsy....then You mean to say I have to create an object..not an array?

Comment: You all mean to say that render() function works with an obect, not an array... Am I right?

Comment: @ Jilson Thomas What is meant by "Its only available in a collection"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying foreach the pager object and assign an array you lose the paging properties, so you will have an array rather than a pager object.
I recommend the following solution for your case:

Controller:

```
public function getAdmins(){

    $search[] =array();
    $search['name']= Input::get('name','');
    $search['uname']= Input::get('uname','');
    $search['role']= Input::get('role','');

    $users = $this->user->findUsers($search);

    return view('users::admins.list')->with('users',$users)->with('search',$search);
}
```

Blade file:

```
@if($users)

    @foreach($users as $user)
         @if(!$user->isUser())
            <!-- Some code here to loop array -->
         @endif
    @endforeach

@else
      No Staffs

@endif 
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

Comment: @ Jeans Marcos: Ok let me to do that

Comment: @ Jeans Marcos: Can you give me your skype ID please?

Comment: I also have gotten the same problem. Getting error like, "Call to a member function links() on array". I can't use the collection, need to use an array. What's the solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

NO, `render()` doesn't work on an object *per se*, neither on the array you are creating out of the required object for the pagination to work (LengthAwarePaginator)

Since you have a collection, and you need one, you could use one of the methods provided to do your filtering, such as [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter).

Something like (untested but should work):

```
$staff = $users->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return !$value->isUser();
});
```